According to these logs, what was the last update?
To update ubuntu there are at least two ways, the GUI interface that comes with the system, and the CLI apt update command series.
I always use the CLI because I'm concerned about the GUI source being tempered. With CLI I have some control over which server I download those update packages from.
The thing is I accidentally touched space bar and downloaded updates using GUI, so I have been trying sporadically to roll back the last update. But to do that, first of course I need to identify the last update. Here's the problem: there wasn't any actual SYSTEM update installed it seems, save for adding some certificates. I could of course be completely wrong.
So I'm pasting the update logs here hoping to have someone id-ing the update for me, I've censored some key phrases in an effort to maximize privacy.
If the certificates addition/update IS the update, feel free to point it out for me. Thanks in advance.
All logs are relevant to the date of the events transpired with 100% confidence.
Also, a few things to consider:
1.The GUI maybe a glorified version of the CLI apt update command, so the log will log it as if I typed those commands
2.It's possible the GUI doesn't log anything at all so id-ing the update isn't possible. In which case I will have to roll back to an earlier date before the update.
3.Based on my judgement, the log detailing last updates described update to a software package and added some certificates - Which is a good news because I can just uninstall that software then reinstall it and no roll-back needed as there's no system level updates.
History.log:
Start-Date: 2024-09-25  14:23:42
Commandline: apt full-upgrade
Requested-By: **** (1000)
Upgrade:*******************, ubuntu-desktop:amd64 ***********************************************************
*************************************************
End-Date: 2024-09-25  14:24:20

Start-Date: 2024-09-26  12:04:44
Commandline: apt full-upgrade
Requested-By: **** (1000)
Upgrade: ********************************, **-certificates:amd64 (20230311ubuntu0.22.04.1, 20240203~22.04.1)
End-Date: 2024-09-26  12:05:01

term.log:
Log started: 2024-09-26  12:04:44
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... ****** files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack ...********************************** ...
Unpacking ************************************************* ...
Preparing to unpack .../**-certificates_20240203~22.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking **-certificates (20240203~22.04.1) over (20230311ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up ************************************************* ...
Setting up **-certificates (20240203~22.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
rehash: warning: skipping **-certificates.crt,it does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL
14 added, 5 removed; done.
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for **-certificates (20240203~22.04.1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/**-certificates/update.d...
Updating Mono key store
Mono Certificate Store Sync - version 6.8.0.105
Populate Mono certificate store from a concatenated list of certificates.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

Importing into legacy system store:
I already trust 137, your new list has 146
Certificate added: ZZ=Atos TrustedRoot Root CA RSA TLS 2021, O=Atos, C=DE
Certificate added: C=ZZ, O=ZZZZZZZ CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY, ZZ=ZZZZ Global Root ZZ9
Certificate added: C=ZZ, O=ZZZZZZZ CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY, ZZ=ZZZZ Global Root ZZ2
Certificate added: C=ZA, O=CommScope, ZZ=CommScope Public Trust ECC Root-01
Certificate added: C=ZA, O=CommScope, ZZ=CommScope Public Trust ECC Root-02
Certificate added: C=ZA, O=CommScope, ZZ=CommScope Public Trust RSA Root-01
Certificate added: C=ZA, O=CommScope, ZZ=CommScope Public Trust RSA Root-02
Certificate added: C=GB, O=Sectigo Limited, ZZ=Sectigo Public Server Authentication Root E46
Certificate added: C=GB, O=Sectigo Limited, ZZ=Sectigo Public Server Authentication Root R46
Certificate added: C=ZA, O=SSL Corporation, ZZ=SSL.com TLS ECC Root CA 2022
Certificate added: C=ZA, O=SSL Corporation, ZZ=SSL.com TLS RSA Root CA 2022
Certificate added: C=ZZ, O="TrustAsia Technologies, Inc.", ZZ=TrustAsia Global Root CA G3
Certificate added: C=ZZ, O="TrustAsia Technologies, Inc.", ZZ=TrustAsia Global Root CA G4
13 new root certificates were added to your trust store.
Import process completed.

Importing into BTLS system store:
I already trust 136, your new list has 146
Certificate added: C=ES, ZZ=Autoridad de Certificacion Firmaprofesional CIF A62634068
Certificate added: ZZ=Atos TrustedRoot Root CA RSA TLS 2021, O=Atos, C=DE
Certificate added: C=ZZ, O=ZZZZZZZ CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY, ZZ=ZZZZ Global Root ZZ9
Certificate added: C=ZZ, O=ZZZZZZZ CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY, ZZ=ZZZZ Global Root CA2
Certificate added: C=ZA, O=CommScope, ZZ=CommScope Public Trust ECC Root-01
Certificate added: C=ZA, O=CommScope, ZZ=CommScope Public Trust ECC Root-02
Certificate added: C=ZA, O=CommScope, ZZ=CommScope Public Trust RSA Root-01
Certificate added: C=ZA, O=CommScope, ZZ=CommScope Public Trust RSA Root-02
Certificate added: C=GB, O=Sectigo Limited, ZZ=Sectigo Public Server Authentication Root E46
Certificate added: C=GB, O=Sectigo Limited, ZZ=Sectigo Public Server Authentication Root R46
Certificate added: C=ZA, O=SSL Corporation, ZZ=SSL.com TLS ECC Root CA 2022
Certificate added: C=ZA, O=SSL Corporation, ZZ=SSL.com TLS RSA Root CA 2022
Certificate added: C=ZZ, O="TrustAsia Technologies, Inc.", ZZ=TrustAsia Global Root CA G3
Certificate added: C=ZZ, O="TrustAsia Technologies, Inc.", ZZ=TrustAsia Global Root CA G4
14 new root certificates were added to your trust store.
Import process completed.
Done
done.
Log ended: 2024-09-26  12:05:01

